# Brownian Motion Winding Number

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-processes, cv.complex-variables

Take a simple random walk $\gamma$ in the complex plane conditioned to start at point $a$ and end at point $b$. For this random walk, we can define the winding number $W_\gamma(a,b)$ around $b$ in the usual way for complex curves.

If instead we have a 2D Brownian motion $Z=X+iY$, then this definition becomes more complicated. For example, if we have a Brownian motion starting at the origin, we can talk about the winding number $\theta_t$ at time $t$ around the origin by solving the stochastic differential equation

$d\theta_t=\frac{X_tdY_t-Y_tdX_t}{|Z_t|^2}$

with initial condition $\theta_0=0$.

The issue is that for Brownian motion, we cannot condition on the path $Z$ to hit a particular point, because this has probability zero. Moreover, by considering annuli around $b$ and the fact that planar Brownian motion moves between concentric annuli with positive probability, it seems to me the situation becomes rather singular.

> **Question:** Is there a sensible generalization for the winding number of a Brownian motion conditioned to hit a single point?

For example, can we look at the limit of the winding number around an annulus about point $b$ whose radius shrinks to zero? I would imagine we would require the Brownian motion to be conditioned to hit some region of positive area just outside the shrinking annulus.

Comment: What's the usual way of defining $W_\gamma(a,b)$? It seems to me that if the curve passes through $b$ there isn't any reasonable winding number around $b$.   Also, shouldn't the curve be closed in order to have a well defined winding number?

Comment: @Pablo: Re your 2nd question: One can define a winding number for an open curve, but it will not in general be an integer, just the total angular turn from end to end divided by $2 \pi$

Comment: @Pablo: so to be clear, b is fixed to be the endpoint of the random walk. As in you are given the walk starts at a and ends at b. 

Comment: Why do you need to hit a point? I see that you need to start from a point, which is no problem. Could you clarify, in which place you need hitting a point?

Comment: @Joseph:  Ok, thanks! I guess the problem with the endpoint being $b$ is that the winding number might be infinite.  But I see now how one could define it as you say.

Comment: Come to think of it, if we wish to measure the winding number around an endpoint of a curve, it might not exist.  Consider for example $t \mapsto (t,t\sin(\frac{1}{t}))$ when $t \to 0$.

Comment: @zhoraster: I mention at the end that I can perhaps consider a disk around a particular point, and condition the brownian motion to end up in this disk, so a single point is not entirely necessary.

Comment: See also the MO question, "[*Twisted random walks*](http://mathoverflow.net/q/138680/6094)", where [*an answer*](http://mathoverflow.net/a/138717/6094) provides several references.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, it is quite possible to condition Brownian motion to hit a given point at a given time. The process is a called a Brownian bridge and the distribution of the winding number of the Brownian bridge is even  known explicitly. It has been computed by Marc Yor in the paper

[Marc Yor: Loi de l'indice du lacet brownien, et distribution de Hartman-Watson. Z. Wahrsch. Verw. Gebiete 53 (1980), no. 1, 71–95.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00531612)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to take the **log** of the Brownian motion and look at the imaginary coordinate.

$$R + i\theta = \log(X+iY)$$

Since $z \mapsto \log z$ is conformal, there exists a *time change* taking one Brownian motion to the other.

Also, notice that $R_t$ is related to the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).