# Twisted random walks

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, random-walks

Suppose the points of two random walks in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are given the
step number (or time) as a third coordinate, so that they become paths in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Here are several pairs of walks of $n=100$ steps, both starting at the origin,
with steps normally distributed with $\sigma=1$:

     [image: TwistedWalks]
I would like to know the expected number of times that one path winds about the other,
as a function of $n$, the number of steps.
I believe for the three pairs illustrated, there is zero winding by $n=100$.
Experiments indicate winding becomes less likely as $n$ grows.
This is a bit counterintuitive to me.

The winding number of path $b(t)$ about path $a(t)$ up to $t=T$ could be defined by counting
the number of times (the normalization of) the vector $b(t)-a(t)$ turns around the origin for $t\in[0,T]$.

Comment: What do you mean by "turns around the origin"? -- For random walks $a(t)$ and $b(t)$, the difference $a(t)-b(t)$ will "go hence and forth" in some sense, I think -- I don't see how you get your winding number from this.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. If one normalizes $b(t)-a(t)$, it can be viewed as a point on the unit circle centered on the origin. (Assume $a(t)=b(t)$ occurs with zero probability.) This point wanders around that unit circle.

Comment: The normalization is clear -- but the issue is that the point won't wander around the unit circle in one direction. It will rather move randomly hence and forth, in both directions -- how do you count this? -- Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: I mean to count just like [the classical winding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number): the total number of times the point travels $2 \pi$ counterclockwise around the circle, taking into account $\pm$ movements, i.e., $-$ cancels $+$.

Comment: Are the two walks independent?

Comment: Can't you equivalently consider a single random walk's winding number about the origin? I think you must put some barrier at the origin, because (in the plane) I think it will hit the origin with non-zero probability. Once you figured out the right set-up, you can convert the discrete random walk into a diffusion equation on the Riemann surface for $\log z$, and if you can solve the diffusion equation you will have your answer.

Comment: @Liviu: Yes, two walks independent.

Comment: @Yoav: In some sense it is a single random walk on the unit circle that determines the winding. So I guess then the expectation should be zero winding, which seems a bit strange to me. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: By symmetry the expectation would be zero winding, but the interesting question would be how the variance grows with time. Here is the surface on which I was suggesting to solve the diffusion equation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Riemann_surface_log.jpg

Comment: @Yoav: Yes, analogous to runs of heads in a sequence of coin flippings: expectation zero, but possibly long runs. Cool re that surface suggestion---Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find here three papers giving at least partial answers to your question:

- M.A. Berger, "The random walk winding number problem: convergence to a diffusion process with excluded area." 1987:
  http://iopscience.iop.org/0305-4470/20/17/028
- Z. Shi, "Windings of Brownian motion and random walks in the plane." 1998:
  http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.aop/1022855413
- Y. Sun, "On the Expected Winding Number of a Random Walk on the Unit Lattice." 2005:
  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/YiSunIntel.pdf

The upshot is that the root mean square winding number grows logarithmically with the number of steps N for $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Excellent, Andreas! Direct hits. Thanks so much!